unable to access rest API from windows environment which is deployed on Linux environment using VM
Unable to access the rest API from my windows 11 Pro OS, where the API is deployed on Linux via Virtual Machine with Apache tomcat server.
I have installed Apache tomcat(10) and deployed my basic Spring boot(3.3.2) rest API application in the Linux environment using.
Within that Linux environment I am able to call the API and getting the response which I tested with the help of "curl" 


I used same software configuration in windows environment, where the application is responding correctly without any issue.
I want to access the same application from Linux VM in Windows environment which is not happening, please refer the post man screen shot.

More questions than answers: where is postman running? You show the curl working from what you say is a Linux vm. And are you really saying you have BOTH wsl and a vm (via some hypervisor) on the windows machine? (You can. I just want to confirm you're saying you DO.) And you have the same tomcat/spring app running in both deployments of Linux? And those have the two ips you showed?  Finally, what if you do the curl within wsl, to the ip shown in postman? And what if you use localhost or 127.0.0.1 in that curl within wsl? (I ask that last question not to be solution but as a diagnostic.)

@charliearehart: i have updated my question, pls let me know.

What Virtualization software do you use for running the Linux VM? How is the VM connected on network level to your PC (usually VM systems allow to specify if it uses NAT mode, bridge mode or host-only).

@Robert I am using VMware Workstation Pro and I tried with NAT mode, bridge mode and host only. nothing helps me to access the rest api from Windows environment.

In host only and bridge mode (then the VM will appear like a physical PC system. If you are in a company network this might cause problems if the MAC addresses are monitored) it should work, but note that the IP address will be different in each mode.

@zameer, you edited the question and your description to remove your references to wsl....so you're not using that after all? Ok. It's just not clear from your reply to me, thus my question--and assuming the answer is yes, I'm offering this as much for other readers, to have context for my first reply. For now, I'll let Robert take it from here, as he seems to have you on the right track.
